# Getting error while run a python script that contains snowflake connector import on Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, automation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch some data from snowflake. The script is running absolutely fine while running on local but when I am trying to run it on Jenkins to automate the process while creating a freestyle project , its giving the following error:

```
import snowflake.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package.
```

`pip install snowflake-connector-python` command is already included in the command line of jenkins.

Looking for a solution on priority basis.

Comment: Is the pipeline running in a venv?

Comment: could you try installing the connector as follows and check if it works: ```python -m pip install snowflake-connector-python```